# could not extract signature dechipering actions ytdl

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, package

I run a bot on Heroku but I like to test it locally before I deploy it, right now I seem to be getting this error only when I run it on Heroku.

```
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121207+00:00 app[worker.1]: events.js:160
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121220+00:00 app[worker.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121222+00:00 app[worker.1]:       ^
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121222+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121223+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not extract signature deciphering actions
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121224+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/sig.js:48:11
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121225+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ytdl-core/lib/request.js:34:9)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121226+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121226+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121227+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121228+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.121229+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
2016-12-05T12:03:56.768468+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-12-05T12:03:56.758114+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Usually I'm ok debugging my own code but I'm not sure where the problem is coming from in this one. It seems like the error is coming from a package called ytdl-core which is what I use to create audio streams for my bot from a youtube link. Is it possible that this is an error with my code? Or is this an error with Heroku or even ytdl-core?

If anyone could basically tell me what this error means and maybe a solution if you guys have any clue about what's going on. If you need anymore information I should be relatively active for the next couple of hours.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I dropped a zero on my ytdl-core version in my package.json file, instead of using version 0.7.20 I was using version 0.7.2 and this fixed my problem.